# Run realtime plotting on python flask using bokeh

Tags: python, heroku, flask, ibm-cloud, bokeh

I am trying to establish a simple realtime plotting scenario using python flask (heroku boilerplate) and bokeh as the plotting library. After plotting the initial graph (data comes from a batch scenario), the graph should update new data points to the figure. Locally the code works perfectly following the [official documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html). But when I try to incorporate the code into my Bluemix application, it throws an IOError, that indicates that there is no bokeh server to connect to:

```
IOError: Cannot push session document because we failed to connect to the server (to start the server, try the 'bokeh serve' command)
```

So I tried to start the bokeh server on Bluemix running

```
call(["bokeh", "serve"])
```

,but it does not work.

Attached their is the complete code for the small use case:

```
    @app.route('/testBokeh', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def PlotWithBokeh():
    sumSessionCounter()
    global X
    global Y
    global n
    alpha = request.form['alpha']
    beta = request.form['beta']
    n = 100
    X = np.random.uniform(0, 100, n)
    e = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
    Y = int(alpha) + int(beta) * X + e
    x = X.reshape(n, 1)
    y = Y.reshape(n, 1)
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr.fit(x, y)
    call(["bokeh", "serve"])

    myfigure = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=400)
    myfigure.line(x.flatten(), regr.predict(x).flatten(), line_width=20, color="red")
    datacoords = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=X, y=Y))
    linea = myfigure.scatter("x", "y", source=datacoords)

    @linear(m=0.05, b=0) #step will increment by 0.05 every time
    def update(step): 
        global X 
        global Y
        new_x = np.random.uniform(0, 5, 1)
        new_y = 10 + 20 * new_x + np.random.normal(0, 1, 1)

        X = np.append(X, new_x)
        Y = np.append(Y, new_y)
        linea.data_source.data["x"] = X
        linea.data_source.data["y"] = Y

    js_resources = INLINE.render_js()
    css_resources = INLINE.render_css()

    script, div = components(myfigure, INLINE)
    html = render_template(
        'plotData.html',
        plot_script=script,
        plot_div=div,
        js_resources=js_resources,
        css_resources=css_resources
    )
    set_curdoc(html)
    #open a session to keep our local document in sync with server
    session = push_session(curdoc())
    curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 10000) #period in ms
    session.show(myfigure)
    session.loop_until_closed()
```

EDIT:

I am pointing in the direction, that I am running the whole application in the bokeh server. To do so, I incorporated the following changes into my Procfile

```
web: python -m bokeh serve /welcome.py
```

Now it doesn't start the app at all, but having a look into the log files let me assume that it might be a good way:

```
2016-09-16 09:59:15,087 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.2
2016-09-16 09:59:15,111 Starting Bokeh server on port 5006 with applications at paths ['/welcome']
2016-09-16 09:59:15,111 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 29
```

ERROR:

```
Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections

App instance exited with guid 618110f2-f477-4427-bd79-6599b4fc2c90 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"618110f2-f477-4427-bd79-6599b4fc2c90", "version"=>"f5212f2d-ec88-40bc-9855-b25213cfc55c", "instance"=>"13d1c8b9ba754088ae368519b098cc20", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1474019881}
```

I intend that it is an issue with the port resolution or some other internal Bluemix issue.

For the reason that Bluemix is using Cloud Foundry, I tried to contact the native port 80, which is used by CF based on my (limited) knowledge in this domain. No it throws a permission error:

```
2016-09-16 10:14:53,226 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.2
ERROR:[Errno 13] Permission denied
Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
```

Comment: Hi! Do you have any progress?

Comment: @Sklavit Yes, the issue was related to my CloudFoundry setup, where I only had one port available. To stream realtime data, you would need to have at least two ports available (app + bokeh server). With this setup, it should work.